# EF created two duplicated FK for a relationship

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I have a two tables which are cities and counties. They are related each other. Although there is only one relationship between them, EF created two duplicated keys in database. I am using EF 6.0.0.0. Sample code at below:

```
    public class County : BaseEntity
{

    public County()
    {

        RegardingCity = new City();

    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CityID { get; set; }

    public virtual City RegardingCity { get; set; }

}

public class City : BaseEntity
{

    public City()
    {

        Counties = new List<County>();

    }

    public int Plate { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<County> Counties { get; set; }

}

and these are the mappers of them

class CountyMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<BiLims.Data.Entities.Common.County>
{

    public CountyMapper()
    {

        this.HasKey(c => c.Id);
        this.Property(c => c.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.Property(c => c.Id).IsRequired();

        this.Property(c => c.Name).IsRequired();

        this.HasRequired(c => c.RegardingCity).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.CityID);

    }

}

class CityMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<BiLims.Data.Entities.Common.City>
{

    public CityMapper()
    {


        this.HasKey(c => c.Id);
        this.Property(c => c.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.Property(c => c.Id).IsRequired();

        this.Property(c => c.Name).IsRequired();

        this.Property(c => c.Plate).IsRequired();

    }


}
```

[image: These are the created tables and their relationship]

What am I doing wrong ? I have searched about this but I couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by your fluent API mapping (much of which is redundant by the way, the conventions of the Entity Framework will pick up the ID and the CityID properties by itself).

By stating that a `City.HasMany()` you introduce the second one to many relation as this means that the one to many relation exists but that `City` does not have a navigation property for it. `City`*does* have an explicit navigation property to `Counties`of the same name, however.

You are safe to remove the one to many mapping altogether!

Comment: It is an extension on the return type of the HasForeignKey extension method.